# More information about df

Tags: command-line

At my work, I have to delete/purge certain things on the HD to our servers. I usually check `df -h` afterwards to check the available space and usage. And sometimes I noticed that this does not update right away. I remember asking my colleagues about this and they mentioned why that was the case but I forgot what they advised me. Does anyone know why `df -h` does not update right away and if there is something I would have to do to get it to update?

Comment: It's probably related to `updatedb` command, but I'm not sure.

Comment: What filesystem are you using?  btrfs usually does this because of the way it works.  And `updatedb` has nothing to do with anything.

Comment: I tried using `fdisk -l` to get the list of filesystems but it doesn't seem to like the syntax (or how I typed it). I will ask my colleagues when I get the chance...I think it is btrfs but I will double check that.

Comment: I verified that it is actually either ext2fs or ext4fs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the reason why from my colleague. The reason why `df` does not update right away is because I would have to restart postgres services in our server. Thanks for the assistance :)

Comment: I cannot until two days from now. But I will.

Answer (score 1):

You need to clear up the filesystem cache using `sync`. sync flushes the filesystem buffers and you should then get the updated filsystem information using `df -h`.

Refer to the manual page of sync for more.

Comment: No: whether the changes are still waiting in the cache or not does not matter -- `df` doesn't bypass the cache and look directly at the disk or anything.